# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1} + \sin \frac{\pi}{n+2} +...+ \sin\frac{\pi}{2n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Calculate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \Bigl(\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1} + \sin \frac{\pi}{n+2} +...+ \sin\frac{\pi}{2n} \Bigr)$$

My answer  :

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1} + \sin \frac{\pi}{n+2} +...+ \sin\frac{\pi}{2n})=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \frac{\pi}{n+k}$

as  for  positive  $x$, $$x- \frac{x^3}{6}  < \sin x   <  x  $$

Now   $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \frac{\pi}{n+k} < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\pi}{n+k}$

By using the Riemann  sum,  $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{\pi}{n+k}= \pi \log 2$$

Is  this  true or false ?

Comment: "my answer  :   $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1} + \sin \frac{\pi}{n+2} +...+ \sin\frac{\pi}{2n})=\sum_{n=1}^{n} \sin \frac{\pi}{n+k}$" That makes no sense at all.

Comment: okss  sorry @zhw....

Comment: $n=1→ k=1$ makes sense.

Comment: Hint: Decompose this into the sum of $\frac\pi{n+k}$ and the sum of $\sin\left(\frac\pi{n+k}\right)-\frac\pi{n+k}$. The former is a Riemann sum. To bound the latter, use $|\sin x -x|\leqslant x^3$ for every nonnegative $x$.

Comment: No, it doesn't, @TakahiroWaki; the limit would be missing.

Comment: Please avoid useless and childish statements such as "Pliz help me................." and "Thanks u".

Comment: okks  @Did..thanks for  suggestion

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, it's just irritating me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sufficiently large $n$, we can approximate this sum as $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{\pi}{k}$, with error $\in\mathcal{O}(n\cdot\frac{1}{n^3})=\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})\to 0$. The asymptotic behaviour is $\pi\ln 2n-\pi\ln n=\pi\ln 2$.